# Construction of a common mean proportional

Tags: geometry, circles

"Given four points, A, B, C, D in order on a straight line construct a point P on BC such that PA.PB = PC.PD"

I assume the end result is to have two right angled triangles AXP with X perpendicular to B and angle AXP a rt angle and PYD with Y perpendicular to C and < PYD a rt angle , PX = PY (being the mean proportionals required) but I cannot see how to get there!  What am I missing?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction is not that direct – and I don’t like it either. Anyway, here it goes:-

Let $AB = x$, $BC = y$ and $CD = z$ be the given lengths of the straight line $ABCD$.

We further let $P$ be at a distance $t$ from $B$.

$PA.PB = PC.PD$ means $(t + x)t = (y – t)(y – t + z)$

Simplifying and re-arranging, we have $t = \frac {y + z}{x + y + z + y}y$ [Edited.]

Dividing the line segment $y$ into a known ratio is not that difficult to construct.

Comment: That seems to work with just one amendment..your denominator on the right should be x + 2y + z...not x + y + 2z..I had a mental block about dividing  y into t and y-t .  Silly..but I will claim the excuse of being old.

Comment: @SeanO'Donovan Nice catch. Fixed. I think I am not any younger than you. I think keep on thinking is the best treatment in rejuvenating the brain.

Comment: I won't claim any deep reason for my looking at maths for fun.  I had a whim to "refill" an old school desk with what was in it when I sat at a similar one 58 years ago.  I then had the whim to see if I still remembered the maths I was taught in the ensuing years.   I smply find working through the exercises pleasurable..much as some like crosswords (I used to) or sudoku.

Comment: @SeanO'Donovan Let’s go back to the construction. I don’t like my answer because the construction is not a direct one. The PA.PB = PC.PD thing led me (as well as many others, I suspect) to think in the direction of “power of a point” naturally. It seems like there are too many hurdles in front if one tries this route.

Comment: I would have preferred a more straightforward geometric answer but it seems to me that yours is the one sought for.  The question is one of the last exercises in Durrell's "New Geometry for Schools" published 1939 and is marked as a question "for those running ahead of the class" suggesting that it is indeed not straightforward.

Comment: @SeanO'Donovan Durell’s book was also my high school textbook 4x years ago.

Comment: @SeanO'Donovan I'm glad to inform you that I have found a much simpler method. See below.

Comment: That is indeed easier and of course, once seen seems so obvious.   As we always used to be told, it should be simple, concise and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This is an easier method.

Step-1 Move the line segment BC vertically upward a number of units to B’C’.

Step-2 Let AC’ and DB’ intersect at X.

Step-3 Draw XT, the perpendicular from X to AD.

[image]

In figure (1), $\frac {XD}{XB’} = \frac {XA}{XC’}$

In (2), $\frac {XD}{XB’} = \frac {TD}{TB}$

In (3), $\frac {XA}{XC’} = \frac {TA}{TC}$

∴ $\frac {TD}{TB} = \frac {TA}{TC}$ and the required result follows.

Comment: 'Tis easy when you know how...Thank you, that is indeed a simpler and geometric method.  I knew I had to be overlooking something obvious.